# Compare two list and if found add data into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a VBA script but I'm struggling with the last section of the code. Let me start by being honest and saying that I'm not really good in VBA coding myself... I can manage and know what to in several situations but I also depend on open source code. For the last section of my script I have the following steps that I'd like it to do;

I have an Excel Workbook in which I post data that is being returned to me by e-mail. I press a button to execute a script and finally the file is being saved with the name Data - "Today's date".xlsx This file will contain after I've executed my code a list of E-mail addresses in column A.

The second file that is already open (because of my executed code) is the bulk-data.xlsx it has about 15.000 lines and in the code that has already been executed it will only show the lines of the last 3 days. The e-mail addresses should be in the bulk-data file in column F. When that email address is found in column F, a line has to be added in column M.

My script for the last step looks like:

```
Dim cell As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, rngFound As Range

currentDate = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

' Define this Workbook as wbA
Set wbA = Workbooks("Data - " & currentDate & ".xlsx")
' Define working sheet in wbA. Change sheet name accordingly
Set ws1 = wbA.Sheets("Data")
' Define data list range in wbA ws1
Set rngA = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

' Define opened Workbook as wbB while opening it.
Set wbB = Workbooks("bulk-data.xlsx")
' Define working sheet in wbB. Change sheet name accordingly
Set ws2 = wbB.Sheets("Performance")
' Define data list range in wbB ws2 (assuming data start from F2 dowm where A1 is Header)
Set rngB = ws2.Range("F2", ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))

' Compare each data in rngA with rngB in wbB to find match
For Each cell In rngA
    Set rngFound = rngB.Find(cell)
    If rngFound Then
        ' Data is found and you want to add something in column M
        ws2.Range("M" & cell.Row) = "Medewerker met deze gebruikersnaam bestaat al. Rollen dienen handmatig te worden toegevoegd in "
    Else     
        MsgBox "Error;" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Medewerker niet gevonden.", vbInformation, "Not Found"    
    End If
Next
```

Hopefully someone can help me on why this script doesn't function.

Comment: When you say "doesn't function", what exactly doeas that entail? Is there an error, or is it just not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, rngFound being a range, and not returning true or fale,  `If rngFound Then` is probably not working. Try `If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then` instead,

Comment: Script does indeed break down on the If rngFound Then. The line is being highlighted when running the script. 
I did try your line and I don't get an error but still it won't work. With that I mean;
It doesn't seem to search the email from Workbook A in Workbook B and when found put the programmed line in column M.

Comment: When I tried it, it worked. But then I named and saved both files first, as this code doesn't name anything. But if you didn't save it first, it should throw an error on `Set wbA = Workbooks("Data - " & currentDate & ".xlsx")`? Are you sure all names are correct? Are you running the code from a third Workbook, or from the Data one?

Comment: It also just printed the message on the row in bulk where it found the data in data. Not next to the actual data that it found. Also, what is the name of your data file if you create one today?

Comment: It should only throw an error on the line `Set wbA = Workbooks("Data - " & currentDate & ".xlsx")` if the date of the day changed. Regarding the file names. Due to privacy matters I changed them a little bit but I've only deleted small sections which shouldn't matter. I tried to change the code to: `If rngFound = True Then` But that way I only get my msgbox msg `MsgBox "Error;" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Medewerker niet gevonden.", vbInformation, "Not Found" `

Comment: As I said, `rngFound` won't return true, it's a range. So it will always go to the `else` or throw an error.  `If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then` should still be working. You might want to change `ws2.Range("M" & cell.Row)` to `ws2.Range("M" & rngFound.Row)` which makes more sense.

Comment: That does the trick! Much appreciated that you helped me over the last hurdle. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you here the VBA codes as I know you can convert the Excel formula to codes. What am I going to tell you the technique of comparing two list A (Bigger) and the List B. In case any data of List B is matched or not matched then data is to be extracted and placed in a separate column. you can either use:

1. `=isna(match(b1,a1:A100,0)`
   This logical test confirming that that particular data of List B data is missing in List A
   So u can proceed now
   `=if(isna(match(b1,a1:A100,0),row(a1:a100))`
2. `=if(countif(a1:a100,b1),row(a1:a100))`
   A link m giving you to visit
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ktZnJWqsjs

Answer (score 0):

Script got fixed by Christofer Weber, thanks for that! Working script is the following:

```
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, rngFound As Range
    
    currentDate = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
    
    ' Define this Workbook as wbA
    Set wbA = Workbooks("Data - " & currentDate & ".xlsx")
    ' Define working sheet in wbA. Change sheet name accordingly
    Set ws1 = wbA.Sheets("Data")
    ' Define data list range in wbA ws1
    Set rngA = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Define opened Workbook as wbB while opening it.
    Set wbB = Workbooks("bulk-data.xlsx")
    ' Define working sheet in wbB. Change sheet name accordingly
    Set ws2 = wbB.Sheets("Performance")
    ' Define data list range in wbB ws2 (assuming data start from F2 dowm where A1 is Header)
    Set rngB = ws2.Range("F2", ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Compare each data in rngA with rngB in wbB to find match
    For Each cell In rngA
    Set rngFound = rngB.Find(cell)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    ' Data is found and you want to add something in column M
    ws2.Range("M" & rngFound.Row) = "Medewerker met deze gebruikersnaam bestaat al. Rollen dienen handmatig te worden toegevoegd in "
    Else     
    MsgBox "Error;" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Medewerker niet gevonden.", vbInformation, "Not Found"    
    End If
    Next
```